# Recover type in parametric composite type

Tags: types, julia

In Julia (< 0.6), when creating a parametric composite type such as `MyType{T}`, is there a clean way to recover `T` from an instance of that type?

Take their example from the doc:

```
type Point{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

I can create an object `p = Point(5.0,5.0)`, `T` here will be matched to `Float64` so that the corresponding object is a `Point{Float64}`. Is there a clean way to recover `Float64` here?

I could do

```
typeof(p.x)
```

But it feels like that's not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you need the type parameter, you should define a parametric method. That is the only proper way to access the type parameter.

So for a `Point`,

```
function doSomething{T}(p::Point{T}) 
    // You have recovered T  
    println(T)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The type is saved in the class information:

`typeof(Point(1, 2)).parameters # -> svec(Int64)`

It's more general than writing a specific function for it, but I'm not sure it's considered official.

Comment: thanks, yes I had seen the `parameters` field of `DataType`, however it felt a bit ugly which is why aviks' solution seems best (more expressive). That being said the solution you quote does the job just fine so +1

Answer (score 0):

There's also `fieldtype`

```
fieldtype(typeof(Point(1.0, 1.0)), :x) # --> Float64
fieldtype(Point, :x) # --> T
fieldtype(Point{Int64}, :x) # --> Int64
```

Not sure how that's any better than just getting the type of the instance though.